# No such file or directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason despite having the file in the main and in the same directory, I keep getting the no such file error. Any help is appreciated.

```
    import time
    def firstQues():

            print('"TT(Announcing): HONING IN FROM SU CASA CUIDAD, (Their hometown)"')
            time.sleep(3)
            print('"VEN EL UN.....(Comes the one.....)"')
            time.sleep(2)
            print('"EL SOLO......(The ONLY.....)"')
            time.sleep(3)
            print('"Campeón NOVATO (NEWBIE CHAMP)"')
            print()


            text_file = open("Questions1.txt", "r")
            wholefile = text_file.readline()
            for wholefile in open("Questions1.txt"):
                    print(wholefile)
                    return wholefile
                    return text_file

    def main():
            firstQues()
            text_file = open("Questions1.txt", "r")
    main()
```

Comment: You can't open the same file three times without closing it first; there is also no point in having two return statements, only the first one will work.

Comment: Please check whether "Questions1.txt" and above python script are in same folder

Comment: They are in the same folder.

Comment: How are you executing the script?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the python script is, what matters is where you're executing it from.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a file in read mode that doesn't exist. Make sure you create a file in a current working directory. Your program executed successfully.

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, it's in the correct directory but now it's only reading one line of the file when I changed text_file.readline() to text_file.read()

Answer (score 0):

```
  with open("Questions1.txt", "r") as f:
       file_data = f.read().splitlines()
  for line in file_data:
      #do what ever you want
```

[How do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution comes down to a paradigm choice, *ask for permission* or *ask for forgiveness*.

Ask for permission: check if the file exists before using

```
import os.path

if os.path.isfile("Questions1.txt"):
  #read file here
```

Ask for forgiveness: try-except block, report if issues

```
try:
  #read file and work on it
except:
  print 'Error reading file'
```

If you use read-write flag, it will create a file when it doesn't exist, but it doesn't seem like you want to write

```
with open("Questions1.txt", "rw") as f:
  #work on file
```

Pick your poison. Hope this helps :)